# When does the officers sit back and laugh?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Rep. Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez claims Border Police agents are forcing
>   migrants to drink out of toilets and live under other extreme
>   conditions — **while the officers sit back and laugh**.

When does the officers sit back and laugh?

> 1. While Rep. Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez claims ...
> 2. While migrants are drinking toilets water.

Comment: the second one, everything after "claims" is part of the claim in this sentence

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as written is ambiguous, and the reason is that it's not possible to tell if *while* modifies everything before it or only the portion that it comes immediately after.

It could be interpreted either way. In order for it to avoid ambiguity, it would need to be rephrased.

Partly as suggested in the question, here are two possibilities:

> 1. While the officers sit back and laugh, Rep. Alexandria Ocasia-Cortez claims Border Patrol agents are forcing migrants to drink out of toilets and live under other extreme conditions.
> 2. Rep. Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez claims Border Police agents are forcing migrants to drink out of toilets and live under other extreme conditions. She also claims that this happens while the officers sit back and laugh.

Note that the second version is exaggerated into two sentences in order to make a point. The same thing could be accomplished by simply removing the dash from the original version. It's really the use of the dash that makes parsing it unclear. (The same problem would have occurred had a comma been used.)

Comment: I think that this is one of those areas where you need context to resolve ambiguity - does it seem more likely that the officers are laughing at a government legislator, or at the migrants?